# Scale image on hover - unexpected behavior on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have an image I'd like to scale when hovering.  My code works just fine on larger screen sizes, but on mobile, it is not working (image looks oddly scaled when I hover).  I think it has to do with the image holder div, but when I try and set the max-width and height on mobile only, I still can't get it to work.

To replicate this issue - try viewing the following snippet in mobile, and hovering over the image (it will behave oddly):

```css
.img-holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:0 auto
}

h4, p{
text-align:center
}

.bio-holder {
  padding-top:10px;
}

.img-fluid.d-block.mb-3.mx-auto.rounded-circle:hover{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
.bioName, .aboutHeading {
   color: #030b07;

}

.bioName {
   font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 p-4 staff-category"> 
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mb-3 mx-auto rounded-circle" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1559454870/team-3.jpg" alt="Card image cap" width="200">
   </div>
   <div class="bio-holder">
    <h4 class="people_name"> <b class='bioNamePreview'>Ronald McDonald</b> </h4>
    <p class="mb-0">CEO and founder</p>
    </div>
</div>
            
            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a margin bottom on the `img.img-fuild`

Just remove it.

```css
.img-holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:0 auto
}

h4, p{
text-align:center
}

.bio-holder {
  padding-top:10px;
}

.img-fluid.d-block.mb-3.mx-auto.rounded-circle:hover{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
.bioName, .aboutHeading {
   color: #030b07;

}

.bioName {
   font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 p-4 staff-category"> 
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mb-3 mx-auto rounded-circle" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1559454870/team-3.jpg" alt="Card image cap" width="200">
   </div>
   <div class="bio-holder">
    <h4 class="people_name"> <b class='bioNamePreview'>Ronald McDonald</b> </h4>
    <p class="mb-0">CEO and founder</p>
    </div>
</div>
            
            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform-origin: center center;` with `transform: scale(1.1);`

and remove `width="200"` and `mb-3` from `img`

And try to be a little bit more focused on CSS prefixes

```
.img-fluid.d-block.mx-auto.rounded-circle:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);

  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

you can use an [online auto prefixer like this](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to save time or prefix extension in your code editor. Please lemme know if it works for you or not.

```css
.img-holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:0 auto
}

h4, p{
text-align:center
}

.bio-holder {
  padding-top:10px;
}

.img-fluid.d-block.mx-auto.rounded-circle:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
    
.bioName, .aboutHeading {
   color: #030b07;

}

.bioName {
   font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-6 col-md-4 p-4 staff-category"> 
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto rounded-circle" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1559454870/team-3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
   </div>
   <div class="bio-holder">
    <h4 class="people_name"> <b class='bioNamePreview'>Ronald McDonald</b> </h4>
    <p class="mb-0">CEO and founder</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine on mobile I checked in my own, just check surely if you disable touch simulation if you test it on the browser?

I gives you a screen to see what I said.

[image]

Comment: You need to hover it in mobile - try that - it is distorted for me.

Comment: hover action as such doesn't exist on mobile because of the lack of a cursor... do you mean focus or active instead?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are experiencing is due to browser specific prefixes. You should add the generic transform property:

```css
.img-fluid.d-block.mx-auto.rounded-circle:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that most mobile devices lack a cursor, so the hover event as such won't be triggered in the same way that in desktop.

You should also consider using more specific class-names instead of mashing functionality into the union of many different ones, for example:

```css
.scale-on:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

### Update:

Taking a closer look, the issue is with the bottom margin of the image, as it messed with the image size. You should remove the `mb-3` class and the `width` attribute (redundant, as `image-fluid` will make its width 100% and the parent container already has max-width specified) from the image element:

```css
.img-holder {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:0 auto
}

h4, p{
text-align:center
}

.bio-holder {
  padding-top:10px;
}

.scale-on:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
        transition: all 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
.bioName, .aboutHeading {
   color: #030b07;

}

.bioName {
   font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 p-4 staff-category"> 
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto rounded-circle scale-on" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1559454870/team-3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
   </div>
   <div class="bio-holder">
    <h4 class="people_name"> <b class='bioNamePreview'>Ronald McDonald</b> </h4>
    <p class="mb-0">CEO and founder</p>
    </div>
</div>
            
            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: still no luck.. if you view the code snippet on mobile, you will see that clicking the image still distorts the image .

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 updated answer to fix the actual issue.